# Ideas for a Jquery and Django multiplayer web chess game

Tags: jquery, django, jquery-ui, web-applications

I would like to know what would be the best design, or the overall view for a webapp project about a multiplayer chess game using Django on the server side and jQuery on the client side.

The project has the following assumptions/premises:

- No chess-specific rules

> > It will be just a game board with free-moving pieces. No turn-tracking, or anything related. Users are free to play arround with pieces over the game board.
> >
> > Real time multiplay

> > Any changes made by one player *(e.g.: move a piece)* are automatically rendered on the oposite player window.

Session saving

> > Users can stop a game session and resume it later.

Drag & drop pieces

> > Pieces occupy defined places over the game board/grid, and cannot be stacked (like the original game).

The Django part doesn't seems too difficult at a first sight. It is the jQuery part (probably jQuery-UI) that intrigues me, though.

I was thinking about using Django to store all the information about the game (piece's position, etc) while leaving jQuery to act like a constructor, based on the game model stored in Django.

Sorry for the information overload, but I really have no idea of what I'm going to need to do to finish a project like this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will recommend you to implement a RESTful API using [django-tastypie](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie) and use [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/) on client side. Paul Uithol has written a small compatibility layer,[backbone-tastypie](https://github.com/PaulUithol/backbone-tastypie), to make `backbone` and `django-tastypie` work together.

If you want to stick to jQuery then you should expose a RESTful API from server and then bind different API calls with DOM events.

Taylor McKay has implemented [Beer Distribution Game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beer_distribution_game), a multiple simulation game to demonstrate basic principles of [Supply Chain Management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supply_chain_management), using HTML5, AJAX, jQuery, JSON, and REST. You should look into [github project](https://github.com/tmckay/beergame2) for his project.

He has used [django-piston](https://django-piston.readthedocs.org/en/latest/documentation.html), a django app similar to `django-tastypie` for implementing a RESTful server. You should look at his [jQuery Code](https://github.com/tmckay/beergame2/blob/master/bgame/static/js/bgame.js) as well his [api app](https://github.com/tmckay/beergame2/tree/master/api).

I hope above information helps you in understanding implementation on multi player games using Django.